# heroku and rabbitmq - unable to run multiple worker dynos

Tags: heroku, rabbitmq, celery

I am using CloudAMPQ addon for Heroku. As RabbitMQ needs a unique node name for each of its process, I run into warning when I scale my worker dynos from 1 to 2 or more:

```
 /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py:71: UserWarning: A node named coworker@fstrk.io is already using this process mailbox!

 Maybe you forgot to shutdown the other node or did not do so properly?
 Or if you meant to start multiple nodes on the same host please make sure
 you give each node a unique node name!
```

My Procfile line looks like this

```
 coworker: celery -l info -A getmybot worker -Q slack -c ${COWORKER_PROCESSES:-4} --hostname coworker@fstrk.io --without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat
```

how do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change `--hostname coworker@fstrk.io` to `--hostname coworker@%%h`

More details in official docs:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.worker.html